# How can I change the default credentials used to connect to Visual Studio Online (TFSPreview) when loading Visual Studio up?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

When I load Visual Studio 2012 up, it will attempt to connect to the previous TFS server that it was connected to.

On one of my machines (that also happens to connect to occasionally TFS2008 and TFS2010 servers) always seems to default to completely the wrong account for connecting to Visual Studio Online (tfspreview), and if I were to try and get the latest version, it'll give an error of the form:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Source Control Explorer
>
> TF204017: The operation cannot be completed because the user (Account Service ([my tfs server]) does not have one or more required permissions (Use) for workspace [my workspace];[my live id].
>
> OK

How can I influence Visual Studio 2012 to default to the correct credentials, rather than a seemingly fictional Account Service one?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I had a very similiar problem as I was not able to connect to TFS with my own credentials. Turned out that the user who had created the image (I was using Hyper-V) stored his account in Credential Manager. There was no way to change this in Visual Studio. To solve the issue, I opened **Credential Manager** in Control Panel and edited the Generic Credentials to be my own account. I closed and opened Visual Studio 2012, and reconnected to TFS. It prompted me for my credentials, but it connected with my account from then on.

Comment: Note that I had to change my credentials under "Windows Credentials", not "Generic Credentials"

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! Just to make it clear, you go to Control Panel --> User Accounts and Family Safety --> Credential Manager, Select Windows Credentials, in the list below, remove the credentials for TFS in the cloud.

Comment: Wish I could vote for this again, as I just had the same issue, and this fixed it first time again :)

Comment: Note that I had to close VS2012 and re-open it after removing credentials - then it worked for me - not before.

Comment: I have a system where I log on using two different domain accounts.  This was causing me to log into TFS using only one account instead of the two.  This fixed my issue.

Comment: Note: I had to actually add the Windows Credential. Nothing was there for the TFS server.

Comment: do you happen to know how can i remove the option of saving the credentials all together?

Comment: Note that you might need to remove the credentials under BOTH "Windows credentials" and "Generic Credentials". I took me w while to understand why TFS still used it even though I had removed it.

Comment: I use Windows 7 with VS 2017 at work. Like Matt Slagle above, we use 2 domain accounts and I was being connected to TFS with the wrong domain so my queries, changes, etc. weren't available. In Control Panel->All Control Panel Items->Credential Manager I removed a Windows Credential, and a Generic Credential for the TFS server. I had to close and restart VS 2017 before it worked and I got connected using the right domain account.

Comment: If you have anything mapped under another username, you'd better make sure you remove those mappings first or you'll lose them and then be unable to remap them without lots of headaches...

Comment: this removed the "you are not authorized" error i was getting on my other visual studio version. it was working well on 2019 but on 2022 i kept getting the error, after the change 2022 asked me for creds and then it worked fine.

Comment: I've got similar 403 error after using a different Microsoft account to access our Azure DevOps. Fixed after updating the credential under Generic Credentials and close all visual studio 2022 instances. The name of the credential looks like `git:https://{organization}.visualstudio.com`.

Answer (score 32):

You need to remove TFS credentials from **Windows Vault** to clear and force to ask new TFS credentials in Visual Studio

1. Go to **Control Panel** (**Start -> Control Panel**).
2. Click **User Accounts** ( or **User Accounts and Family Safety->User Accounts** in Windows 7 Machine)
3. Click **Credential Manager** (or **Manage your credentials**)
4. In Credential Manager page, you can see the two type of credentials

   ```
      i. Windows Credentials
      ii. Generic Credentials
   ```

5.Click on two credentials modify link,  click the link **Remove from vault** to remove stored TFS credentials.

Now, When you login into Visual Studio you will be asked to give credentials to connect TFS.

**Note**: Don't forgot to uncheck the option **Remember my credentials** to force to ask credentials for every TFS connections.

Comment: Are TFS credentials named like "TFSsomething", I am asking because I cannot see anything with TFS phrase in it.

Answer (score 13):

I tried opening my Credential Manager but could not find any credentials in there that has any relation to my TFS account.

So what I did instead I logout of my hotmail account in Internet Explorer and then clear all my Internet Explorer cookies and stored password as detailed in this blog: [Changing TFS credentials in Visual Studio 2012](http://www.jayway.com/2012/12/17/changing-tfs-credentials-in-visual-studio-2012/)

[image]

After clearing out the cookies and password, restart IE and then relogin to your hotmail (or windows live account).

Then start Visual Studio and try to reconnect to TFS, you should be prompted for a credential now.

Note: **A reader said that you do not have to clear out all IE cookies, just these 3 cookies**, but I didn't test this.

```
cookie:@login.live.com/
cookie:@visualstudio.com/
cookie:@tfs.app.visualstudio.com/
```

Comment: I experienced the same issue as this poster.  There was no entry in the account manager for TFS.  Clearing passwords and cookies out of IE fixed the issue for me, however I did not restart IE or log back into anything with it.  I just restarted VS2012 and TFS prompted me for credentials.

Comment: This is the solution to clearing credentials used by TFS for VisualStudio.com.

Comment: do you happen to know how can i remove the option of saving the credentials all together?

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this same issue. Someone had logged onto my computer and used their TFS credentials. I'm running VS2012, Windows 7, and the network admins have Credential Manager disabled.

Run this command from a command window with the same user your running visual studio as.

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr
```

You'll see a popup with all your stored credentials. Remove the one for your TFS server.

**Note:**  You will need to restart visual studio because it caches the tfs credentials.

Comment: I cannot somehow fire up "User Accounts". I've used your command and it worked well.

Comment: do you happen to know how can i remove the option of saving the credentials all together?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to reset visual studio setting

1. Open Visual Studio Command Prompt
2. Enter command `Devenv /ResetSettings`

It will remove already saved TFS account and ask for credentials

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8:

Control Panel -> (Search for) Credentials Manager -> Check Web Credentials

this worked for me...

Comment: As this duplicates any existing answer, you probably should vote it up, rather than duplicating the answer

Answer (score 0):

After failing with cleaning the Credentials from the Manager and clearing the VS cache, consider to **repair Visual Studio** from the Visual Studio Installer (VS2017). I personally found no other solution working.

Answer (score -4):

i found another solution:

1. start session in TEAM
2. go to SOURCE CONTROL and select WORKSPACE (mark in red)
3. then Add new Workspace... why?
4. because you dont work in the same workspace whey you change your account in TFS (i dont know why)
5. and ready to MAP your project again.

Its 100% guaranteed to work.

Comment: This did not work for me. I'm not convinced the credentials are even stored in the workspace.