# Can't remove workspace from TFS

Tags: tfs

I want to add my project from Visual Studio 2012 to my TFS server, but it says the path is already mapped for workspace pc;administrator (this is a *local workspace*).

I have tried the command tool `tf` but it says that there are no workspaces, so I can't delete the workspace that is conflicting.

I'm running Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2012. TFS is on a windows server 2012.

Comment: Did you map your local workspace to a different TFS Server (or TFS Preview)? Also, is this a team project or a local project? Has this project ever been associated with a different TFS Server?

Comment: It is a new project, created in visual studio. But i did create a project yesterday with the same name that i deleted again. Been testing TFS. So it could be that the system thinks the project from yesterday still exists on that file location. Thats why i need to delete the workspaces.

Comment: Have you deleted the project in windows explorer from your local workspace?

Comment: Yes i just deleted the folder from windows explorer.

Comment: ctrl+q -> workspaces -> remove ?

Comment: i dont know where to press ctrl+q?

Comment: It do not show the workspace that it mention when i try to add the project to the TFS.

Comment: The working folder C:\users\poul\documents\vs2012\projects is already in use by the workspace s093294-laptop;administrator on computer s093294-laptop.    (And the solution that im trying to add is located at \projects\myproject\

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16659/discussion-between-aclear16-and-s093294)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the current project location, the folder on your physical machine, is mapped to a different TFS server. To add it to source control you need to move it to a physical location not associated with a TFS server.

**Edit**
To remove the offending workspace:

1) Use the "Team" menu to connect to the TFS Server that you do NOT want to be mapped to

2) Use ctrl+q --> workspaces to access the workspaces menu

3) Remove the workspace

4) Change to the TFS Server you WANT to be mapped to using the "Team" menu again

5) ctrl+q --> workspaces

6) Add a new workspace

Comment: Yes as talked about in chat, this works. A solution for unmapping the local path such it can be used again will be help full.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @aclear16. I had a different error message that also got resolved this way: the message said "Multiple identities found matching workspace name 'xxx' and owner name 'abc'. Please specify one of the following workspace specs:" followed by a list of workspaces. I connect to 2 different TFS servers, one local and one remote. The issue was that I had the same workspace xxx mapped in both instances. After deleting the workspace from one of the TFS servers, things worked as expected

Answer (score 4):

Try any of these steps out. Some of them may not be applicable to you.

To clear up "cached workspace" and remove workspace mapping.

1. On Control Panel > User > Credential Manager
   Remove Windows Account and Generic Account that points to TFS.
   [How can I change the default credentials used to connect to Visual Studio Online (TFSPreview) when loading Visual Studio up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407668/how-can-i-change-the-default-credentials-used-to-connect-to-tfspreview-when-load)
2. On IE, remove cached password.
   http://www.jayway.com/2012/12/17/changing-tfs-credentials-in-visual-studio-2012/
3. Remove stored username/password:
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/08/29/clearing-the-credentials-for-connecting-to-a-team-foundation-server.aspx

   > rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr
4. Delete workspace. On VS2012 command line, run the following:

   > tf.exe workspace /delete workspacename;owner /server:serveraddress
   >   http://mycomputeradventures.blogspot.com/2012/01/removing-tfs-workspaces-from-old-users.html
5. Clear Up cached workspace mapping. On VS2012 command line, run the following:

   > tf.exe workspaces /remove:*   (or /s:http//oldserver:8080)
   >   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/09/12/path-is-already-mapped-in-workspace.aspx

Answer (score 2):

if you use Visual studio 2012 go

`C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache`

or if it is Visual studio 2013 go

```
C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache
```

Remove all things under it.

Comment: Does not work, when you start visual studio 2010 it regenerates the mapping AND the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this is to go to your AppData and delete the TFS cache (depending on the version 3.0 or 4.0)

C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache 
or 
C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache

Comment: Thanks... I tried everything from Visual Studio to TF.EXE - but nothing worked. This did!

Answer (score 1):

1. First we will check the list of workspaces from VS 2015 Developer command prompt,

   Ex - tf workspaces /owner:*
2. Now we will get the xml format from VS 2017 Developer command prompt which will have ‘owner id’ for the particular workspace,

   Example 1 - tf.exe workspaces /owner:* /computer:ComputerName 
   /collection:https://YOUR-TFS-URL.visualstudio.com /format:xml
3. We can now delete the workspace for the particular user,

   Example 1- Tf workspace /delete ComputerName;email@email.com 
   /server:"https://URL.visualstudio.com"

   OR

   Example 2 - Tf workspace /delete ComputerName;1e178c77-bb8b-6f05-bf99
   /server:https://URL.visualstudio.com

   (Where 1e178c77-bb8b-6f05-bf99  is ID of the workspace which you get from Step 2 XML 
   format)
4. Again we will check the list of workspaces from VS 2015 Developer command prompt,

   Ex - tf workspaces /owner:*

Answer (score 0):

Well I couldnt find my troublesome workspace, which prompted me to copy the local code folder into another name and I created a new workspace mapping that folder.

Next up I added the new solution to the TFS via VS 2012 using Add Source Control.