# No security on TFS+Git Service?

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

(see update below)

I'm evaluating Team Foundation Service and observing a somewhat strange behavior. Since I understand that TFS+Git repositories are private - I thought to see how security is managed.

So I changed my Visual Studio 2012 Git Settings to use a "Fake" user - I wasn't asked for any password - see below:

[image]

After that, I added some "fake.txt" file, committed changes and pushed them to the server repository.

To my surprise - the server allowed me to do it - and now this "fake user" commit actually appears in my TFS repository:

[image]

I wasn't asked for a password at any stage. 
What am I doing wrong? Or there's no security at all in TFS service?

Thank you,
  Boris.

**UPDATE:** here's what I found so far:

- The user/email described in Git settings has nothing to do with the user who actually authenticates, as Nathan explained.
- VS2012 uses IE on the background, in order to authenticate with TF service. As a result, if there's any instance of IE running, which is already authenticated (or if it's "remember me" auto-authenticated) - that's the authentication which will be used. IMHO, this is ugly, but I can live with that.
- Worse than that - you also need to sign-out in "Configure Team Projects" dialog (which sometimes is hidden, when logon is managed via control panel's "Manage Credentials" feature - see here [How can I change the default credentials used to connect to Visual Studio Online (TFSPreview) when loading Visual Studio up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407668/how-can-i-change-the-default-credentials-used-to-connect-to-tfspreview-when-load)). Still ugly, but I can live with that as well.

So for the original question - I found some kind of solution.

**But,** what still remains a mystery is that there's no way to figure out who that "Fake User" really was. In other words, the following workflow seems to be the current standard:

- Logon as some "RealUser", this will be well-authenticated via IE or GitHub client
- Change your details, so that you'll be "FakeUser"
- "Do bad stuff to files in the repo" > commit > push
- TF service will accept the change (because you're authenticated as "RealUser")
- But the damage in the repo will appear as done by "FakeUser" and I couldn't find any UI/command which "extracts" the real authenticated user who did the change (see the screenshot above, from the TFS web UI - no mention of my real authenticated username/liveID).

Interestingly, GitHub has pretty much the same behavior, but there is somewhat complicated workaround - you can go to your collaborators, select each collaborator and then check collaborator's activity - you'll see the "Fake" push operation there. This ease of impersonation is even officially admitted by github here: https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user

So considering all the above - my question now is:

**Is there really no way to prevent/detect malicious/accidential user impersonation in TF service?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of digging - I found somewhat acceptable solution:

- Navigate browser to repository > CODE > Commits
- Select the relevant commit and expand the arrow near the "FakeUser" authoring:

  [image]
- Voila! The real "pusher" username is shown

  [image]

Comment: If you ever decide to move your repository, e.g. to the Azure DevOps cloud service, the person who pushed the commit will not be copied, so this information will get lost if you don't back up the TFS database. The new solution involves requiring commits to be digitally signed by a whitelisted user. However, this requires some customization. There isn't a simple checkbox for that.

Answer (score 0):

You were asked for a username and password when you connected to the TF server and cloned the repo. The username and password is cached. You can actually do this with any git repo by setting the user.name and user.email settings (which is what the UI you are showing is doing). The commit username for git actually aren't the same as the security for access the git service - which is why you can do what you did.

Rest assured, the server is secured with your TFS credentials.

Comment: Thanks, but then - how to I change my real, secure, login credentials (e.g. if I indeed want to connect with a real - but different username)?

Comment: To expand on the Git part: Git does not have any authentication or authorization mechanism built in. Everyone who has physical access can push to and pull from it. The server is what adds an authentication layer, which is completely separate from Git’s internal commit attribution settings.