# TFS Error occurring in Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am getting the following error in Visual Studio:

TF30063: You are not authorized to access (my server address here).

The TFS server is actually on Visual Studio Online and I've logged into it separately several times today so the server is definitely available and I was able to check-in stuff to my TFS server earlier today.

There are two things that I think may have contributed to this error but I don't know how to fix them.

1. When asked for the Login, I used the wrong email address a few times and the login box popped up another two or three times before disappearing.
2. I installed the HTML Agility Pack through Nuget, uninstalled it, then re-installed it.

I am not sure if either of these are causing the error but the result is that I can't check-in anything.

Any ideas about how to fix this?  I can re-install Visual Studio but I don't want to and to just face the same issue at the end.

Comment: It might be worth [clearing the credentials used to connect](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12407668/50447) and trying again?

Comment: Indeed. Clearing the credentials cache should work. take a look here in addition to what @RowlandShaw suggested: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/08/29/clearing-the-credentials-for-connecting-to-a-team-foundation-server.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure which credentials to clear.  I forgot to say I am using Windows 8 and VS2012.  The thing is, VS isn't even prompting me now to enter any credentials, it just gives me that error straight away.

Comment: I had no luck with clearing credentials and passwords.  In the end I re-installed Windows and VS and that worked.  Not ideal but it's done now.