# TFS showing Checked in by name as Service Account

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have online TFS account.

Whenever I do a check-in it shows check in done by "Service Account(TFS)" instead of my name.

I want to show my name against the Checked-In by Name.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please make sure you connect the online TFS (VSTS) with the correct account.

If connect with wrong account, you need to remove TFS credentials from Windows Vault to clear and force to ask new TFS credentials in Visual Studio. Please reference this thread: [How can I change the default credentials used to connect to Visual Studio Online (TFSPreview) when loading Visual Studio up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407668/how-can-i-change-the-default-credentials-used-to-connect-to-visual-studio-online) to do that.

If the account is correct, just please check your VSTS account **Profile**, make sure the full name is not "Service Account(TFS)". If it is, just change it to your name, save the profile and check in again, check the **Checked-In** by Name, it will be changed to your name.
[image]