# Visual Studio keep requesting to choose azure account even if logged in

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS 2017 with an Azure account. The account is logged in and I can see the account details at the top right corner.

When I try to restore Nuget packages, I keep getting a window telling me to select the azure account I want to use, and my account is an option to select. Even when I select my account, the window keeps popping back over and over, and I can't seem to get the packages..

What can be done?

Comment: community edition?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Enterprise edition

Comment: I had something similar a few days ago in VS2019. It helped for me to completely remove the account from VS and then re-add it.

Comment: @silent at least logging out and logging back in didn't help

Answer (score 2):

Two things you could try,

**1)Try to clear the invalid cached data:**

i) Close visual studio

ii) delete %localappdata%.IdentityService\

2) Report this problem via Visual **`Studio>Help>Send Feedback>Report a problem.`** This opens a new instance of "Visual Studio Feedback" which might solve your issue.

Comment: both didn't work.. I'm trying to reinstall Visual Studio, but this time VS professional

Comment: That's really strange! is your account active?

Answer (score 0):

I remember facing a similar issue of being asked to sign-in repeatedly on a different workstation. I had to go to the Credential Manager to remove saved creds and re-login with mine. Please check if that helps.

Comment: Signing out and signing back in did not help

Comment: Did you remove your creds from Windows Credential Manager before signing in?

Comment: Could you edit your answer with instructions of how to do it? And then I can try

Comment: You can look up if your creds are saved in Credential Manager by going to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials.

A couple other ways are mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407668/how-can-i-change-the-default-credentials-used-to-connect-to-visual-studio-online

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what triggered my problems, but I assume I had problems with my PAT credentials at some point and then I started to modify nuget.config (can be found here: %APPDATA%\NuGet). In the end I had the correct credentials but a wrong address in my nuget.config and just did not notice the small difference. Unfortunately VS' only reaction was to keep asking me for my credentials when trying to connect me to the wrong NuGet feed address.

Instead of this (I use my-repo instead of the actual name):

```
<add key="my-repo" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-repo/_packaging/my-repo/nuget/v3/index.json" />
```

I had this:

```
<add key="my-repo" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/in3/_packaging/my-repo/nuget/v3/index.json" />
```

I assume I had taken it from some other post or tutorial instead of azure's Artifacts area (https://dev.azure.com/my-repo/mc-projects/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=my-repo)

So even though I had the correct credentials in the nuget.config VS kept asking me for the credentials because of the wrong URL :-(
The only hint that I got from VS was "Error Code:  16000" in the credentials dialog when clicking the `...`
But that always made me suspect the credentials.